# Build adding [] to "" enclosed value in switch statement

Tags: switch-statement

I am writing a query using the switch function. When I enclose the Value in "" in the build window when I go to execute the query Access has enclosed the Value statement in [] and prompts me to provide a value. What am I doing wrong?

The switch statement before I close the build window is:

```
OverUnder: Switch([zVAR Days Decision-Open]![Priority Level]="Emergency" 
And [zVAR Days Decision-Open]! [NewDaysToDecision])<=10,”Under”, , [zVAR Days Decision-Open]![Priority Level]="Emergency" 
And [NewDaysToDecision]>10,”Over”, [zVAR Days Decision-Open]![Priority Level]="Level 1" 
And [NewDaysToDecision]<=10,”Under”, [zVAR Days Decision-Open]![Priority Level]="Level 1" 
And [NewDaysToDecision]>10,”Over”, [zVAR Days Decision-Open]![Priority Level]="Level 2" 
And [NewDaysToDecision]<=30,”Under”, [zVAR Days Decision-Open]![Priority Level]="Level 2" 
And [NewDaysToDecision]>30,” Over”, [zVAR Days Decision-Open]![Priority Level]="Level 3" 
And  NewDaysToDecision]<=30,”Under”, [zVAR Days Decision-Open]![Priority Level]="Level 3" 
And [NewDaysToDecision]>30, ”Over”)
```

I'm not sure you can use an And statement to include multiple criteria in a switch statement. Is that the issue?

Comment: What program/language do you use?

Comment: This is done just in MS Access in the build criteria window.